# Где найти Java Runtime версия 52?

Tags: java, плагин, runtime, minecraft, bukkit-api

Не запускается плагин с ошибкой:

```
[15:22:52] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\rst.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rst/main/RSTMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:139) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:394) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:301) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:383) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:185) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rst/main/RSTMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:163) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    ... 7 more
[15:22:52]
```

После того, как поискал про эту ошибку, оказалось что рантайм сервера (версии 1.15.2)  не поддерживает старшие версии.
Как определить вообще какая версия рантайма стоит и где найти нужный(52)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю по таблице можно с ориетнтироваться

```
Java SE 17 = 61 (0x3D hex),
Java SE 16 = 60 (0x3C hex),
Java SE 15 = 59 (0x3B hex),
Java SE 14 = 58 (0x3A hex),
Java SE 13 = 57 (0x39 hex),
Java SE 12 = 56 (0x38 hex),
Java SE 11 = 55 (0x37 hex),
Java SE 10 = 54 (0x36 hex),[3]
Java SE 9 = 53 (0x35 hex),[4]
Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
Java SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
Java SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).
```

Вам нужен **[Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)**

Comment: Да, оказалось что у меня стояла аж 14 версия. Спасибо!